# Efficient loading of Pygamescreens to 2D-lists

Tags: python, pygame

Im looking for a fast way to do this:

```
def load(screen):
    x, y = (screen.get_size()[0], screen.get_size()[1])
    list = []
    out = []
    for pln in range(x):
        for prn in range(y):
            liste.append(screen.get_at([pln, prn]))
        out.append(copy.deepcopy(list))
        list = []
    print ("finish")
    #print(len(out))
    return copy.deepcopy((out))
```

screen is the object created with `pygame.display.set_mode(*size*)`

here, I try to write the colors from get_at in a 2d-list. Is there a built-in function from Pygame to do this? I mean, this Code is far to slow...

Comment: Why do you have the `copy.deepcopy` calls in there? They are completely unnecessary and will slow down your execution _extreme_.

Comment: at least post code that actually works.

Comment: @hop What is the problem? What doesn't work. The code doesn't have any (obvious) errors and the logic if good?

Comment: @MegaIng: try to run it

Comment: You should open a new question, describing your _actual_ question. Putting the screen's content into lists can't be the objective. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can almost triple the speed by using `pygame.surfarray`.

But I don't thing you actually want to have a list of the pixels. Please post a new question with you underling problem, as @hop suggested.

```
def load(screen):
    return pygame.surfarray.pixels2d(screen).tolist()
```